# ListView から Fragment、それとも ListView から new Activity？

Tags: android, java, android-studio

今は楽譜のアプリを作っていて、最初に、曲名のリストが`ListView`で、`TextView`として出てきます。

プログラミングやAndroid Studioにおいて、私はまだ初心者なんですが、`setOnItemClickListener()`のタイミングで、その歌の楽譜が表れてほしいです。
ただ、別の`Fragment`に移るか、完全に新しい`Activity`を作った方がいいですか？

楽譜に入ってBackボタンを押したら`ListView`に戻ってほしいけど、５０個の歌まで至ったらそんなにたくさんの`Activity`を作ったら良くないですかな？

初心者であってすみませんが、よろしくお願いします(^_^)

Answer (score 1):

50曲それぞれのActivityを開いたとしても、メモリには1個しか残りませんので、Activityで実現しても問題にはなりません。

初心者なのであれば、Fragmentを使うと色々難しい箇所が出てきますので、まずはActivityで作ってみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: そうですか！なら、それをやってみます(^_^)

ありがとうございます！